# ember - recommended way to fetch a collection of objects to use as menu options without them being considered part of the model

Tags: ember.js, associations

I have a model `Foo` which has a field `barId` which has a `belongsTo` relationship to a model named `Bar`.  I want to have a menu of Bars to set the barId value in my "new" Foo template.

I've already created a select component which displays things properly.

Where is the appropriate place for me to do a JSON fetch of the Bar collection?  I'm assuming it should be stored in the controller as that decorates the model and makes extra context available to the template.

Doing an `RSVP.hash()` in the router's `model()` doesn't seem appropriate to me, as it would consider the `Bar` collection part part of the `Foo` model.  Should I be using the router's `afterModel()/setupController()`, the controller's `init()` or set this up somewhere else?

Sorry I don't have a jsFiddle or anything, I don't know how to set one up now that my code requires babel.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It kind of depends when the data is necessary.  If it needs to be loaded before the template is shown `afterModel` is a great hook to enforce this.  If it can be loaded asynchronously, a computed property in the controller or during `setupController` would work fine.  If it's something you plan on using all over the application, potentially a service would be the correct location for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out to be a non-issue as using `Ember.RSVP.hash()` in my router's `model()` without using setupController() as it defaults to model.foo, model.bar, etc, which you can access in controllers/templates/etc.

What I was originally worried about was that the other collections/objects I fetched from the store would be stored along with my 'model' when I did a 
`model.save()`, but instead I'd be using  `model.foo.save()`,